Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml
I am encountering a persistent issue where our .NET application fails to locate a required assembly (System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml, Version=4.1.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a).
Interestingly, when I restart the application, the issue does not reoccur, and everything works as expected. This behavior suggests a possible race condition or timing issue during initialization.
Any guidance or best practices to prevent this issue would be greatly appreciated!

add dependency redirect

Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project? This can resolve some assembly loading issues. Regarding System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml, did you install it via Nuget? If so, make sure the related NuGet packages are all the latest versions. Additionally, you can add assembly binding redirects in the configuration file to ensure that the referenced assembly versions are consistent: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions
